# изменение сообщения в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

я хочу сделать что бы на команду a_or_b высылалась inline клавиатура с выбором a или b при нажатии например на a что то делалось и снизу была кнопка с текстом назад при нажатии возвращало на выбор a или b, я хочу это реализовать в одном сообщение. Я сделал вот такой код

```py
class MainStates(StatesGroup):
    MENU = State()
    ACTION_A = State()
    ACTION_B = State()


@router.message(Command('a_or_b'))
async def a_or_b(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Отправляем сообщение с клавиатурой выбора кнопок A и B
    msg = await message.reply(text='Выберите кнопку A или B', reply_markup=a_or_b_inline())

    # Устанавливаем состояние, в котором находимся (MENU)
    await state.set_state(MainStates.MENU)

    # Сохраняем message_id сообщения, чтобы в дальнейшем изменить его текст и клавиатуру
    await state.update_data(msg_id=msg.message_id)


@router.callback_query(MainStates.MENU)
async def process_callback_menu(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    if callback.data == 'button_a':
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback.id, text="Вы выбрали A")
        # Выполняем какие-то действия при выборе кнопки A

        # Устанавливаем состояние, в котором находимся (ACTION_A)
        await state.set_state(MainStates.ACTION_A)

        # Отправляем сообщение с текстом и клавиатурой для выбора кнопки
        message_id = (await state.get_data()).get('msg_id')
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, text='Подтвердите выбор', message_id=message_id,
                                    reply_markup=a_or_b_inline_next())

    elif callback.data == 'button_b':
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback.id, text="Вы выбрали B")

        # Выполняем какие-то действия при выборе кнопки B

        # Отправляем сообщение с текстом и клавиатурой для выбора кнопки
        message_id = (await state.get_data()).get('msg_id')
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, text='Подтвердите выбор', message_id=message_id,
                                    reply_markup=a_or_b_inline_next())


@router.callback_query(F.text == 'back', MainStates.ACTION_A, MainStates.ACTION_B)
async def process_callback_back(callback_query: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)

    # Отправляем сообщение с текстом и клавиатурой для выбора кнопок A и B
    message_id = (await state.get_data()).get('msg_id')
    await bot.edit_message_text('Выберите кнопку A или B', message_id, reply_markup=a_or_b_inline())

    # Возврат к начальному состоянию (MENU)
    await state.set_state(MainStates.MENU)
```

клавиатура:

```py
def a_or_b_inline():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.button(text='A', callback_data='button_a')
    keyboard.button(text='B', callback_data='button_b')
    keyboard.adjust(2)
    return keyboard.as_markup()


def a_or_b_inline_next():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.button(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
    return keyboard.as_markup()
```

можете ли вы исправь этот код почему он не работает [весь код если кому нужен](https://github.com/dratyti22/telegram_bot/blob/master/core/handlers/a_or_b.py)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь изменить текст N на текст N. Также, советую вам приложить лог ошибки

Comment: @ArthurLangley-Reddle привет, да, ошибки нету просто появляется текст с кнопками но при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как посмотрел у тя была ошибка(В следующий раз приклепряй, какую ошибку выдает), что ты айди чата не указал, посмотри вроде ошибок быть не должно

```
def a_or_b_inline():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.button(text='A', callback_data='button_a')
    keyboard.button(text='B', callback_data='button_b')
    keyboard.adjust(2)
    return keyboard.as_markup()


def a_or_b_inline_next():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.button(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
    return keyboard.as_markup()

class MainStates(StatesGroup):
    MENU = State()
    ACTION_A = State()
    ACTION_B = State()


@dp.message(Command('a_or_b'))
async def a_or_b(message: Message, state: FSMContext):

    # Отправляем сообщение с клавиатурой выбора кнопок A и B
    msg = await message.reply(text='Выберите кнопку A или B', reply_markup=a_or_b_inline())

    # Устанавливаем состояние, в котором находимся (MENU)
    await state.set_state(MainStates.MENU)

    # Сохраняем message_id сообщения, чтобы в дальнейшем изменить его текст и клавиатуру
    await state.update_data(msg_id=msg.message_id)


@dp.callback_query(MainStates.MENU)
async def process_callback_menu(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    if callback.data == 'button_a':
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback.id, text="Вы выбрали A")
        # Выполняем какие-то действия при выборе кнопки A

        # Устанавливаем состояние, в котором находимся (ACTION_A)
        await state.set_state(MainStates.ACTION_A)

        # Отправляем сообщение с текстом и клавиатурой для выбора кнопки
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, text='Подтвердите выбор', message_id=callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=a_or_b_inline_next())

    elif callback.data == 'button_b':
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback.id, text="Вы выбрали B")

        # Выполняем какие-то действия при выборе кнопки B

        # Отправляем сообщение с текстом и клавиатурой для выбора кнопки
        # message_id = (await state.get_data()).get('msg_id')
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, text='Подтвердите выбор', message_id=callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=a_or_b_inline_next())
        await state.clear()


@dp.callback_query(F.data.startswith('back'))
async def process_callback_back(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback.id)

    # Отправляем сообщение с текстом и клавиатурой для выбора кнопок A и B
    # message_id = (await state.get_data()).get('msg_id')
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id ,text='Выберите кнопку A или B', message_id=callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=a_or_b_inline())

    # Возврат к начальному состоянию (MENU)
    await state.set_state(MainStates.MENU)
```

Comment: у меня ошибки нету, просто при вызове команды, она просто не работала как я хочу, клавиатура вызывается с выбором но при нажатии ничего не происходит, а я хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку это сообщение изменялось, но оно не изменяться

Comment: Подправил ответ, у тебя ошибки были с состояниями, когда ты ловил кнопку назад, он её не видел из-за того, что ты не поставил ему состояние, которое в фильтре было(вообше не вижу смысла в state тут), заменил тебе получение id сообщения на более простой, щас по идее должно всё работать

Comment: да это заработала, спасибо за помощь, но у меня есть вопрос почему если регистрировать через dp то все работает, а если через router то ни работает?

Comment: это не изза этого, у вас просто,  чтобы поймать кнопку назад, надо было, чтобы у вас одновременно было состояние ACTION_A и ACTION_B, что невозмонжо, поэтому я сделал так, отключил стояние и сделал так, чтобы он просто ловил кнопку

Comment: я нашел способ как можно сделать легче изменение текста, но я щас проверял его если я его регистрировал через router в другом файле он не работал, а если вызывал через dp то он работал почему так происходит?